# R: Re-order numeric vector by name using custom order

Tags: r, vector, numeric

I have a a numeric vector and want to re-order by name, using a custom order.

```
x <- sample(1:20, 5)
names(x) <- c("feb", "may", "mar", "jan", "apr")
x
feb may mar jan apr 
  7  10   5  13  11
```

As you can see, the vectors are not in month order

### Desired output

I wish to re-order this character vector through month order using the names, i.e. `jan, feb, mar, apr, may...`

How is this possible?

note: I am after a method that can be used on all names/character strings, rather than specifically date objects

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We can convert the `names` of 'x' to `factor` and settting the `levels` to the `month.abb` in lowercase, apply the `order` and get the 'x' in that order.

```
x[order(factor(names(x), levels=tolower(month.abb)))]
jan feb mar apr may 
 13  7   5  11  10
```

The conversion to `factor` with `levels` specified can be applied to any character vector in a custom order, otherwise, by default, the ordering is based on alphabetical order i.e.

```
x[order(names(x))]
```

Suppose, if want the order to be say, 'jan', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'feb', use that as `levels` in the `factor` call

```
x[order(factor(names(x), levels = c('jan', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'feb')))]
```

---

As the OP posted another vector in a custom order in the comments

```
x1 <- c(icecream = 3, jelly = 4, fruit = 5)
x1[order(factor(names(x1), levels = c("jelly", "fruit", "icecream")))]
#   jelly    fruit icecream 
#      4        5        3
```

Comment: Hi there, i'm after a general method that can be used on all character class/names, rather than one restricted to months/date objects

Comment: @G.Gip The character elements are ordered by alphabets, so if that is what you wanted, `x[order(names(x))]`, but your example seems to be based on a custom order on month names.  If it is a custom order, then the `factor`, `levels` approach is generic one.

Comment: No. Not order by alphabet, a custom order. For example, if you had a vector `icecream = 3, jelly = 4, fruit = 5` and wanted it to be ordered `jelly = 4, fruit = 5, icecream = 3`.

Comment: @I know this is off-topic, but to avoid opening a new question for a small thing. If I wanted to colour a barplot using a legend based on these names, e.g. I want blue bars for winter months and red bars for summer months, with the following category `winter = dec:feb, summer = mar:may` or using the other example, yellow barplots for sweets (`jelly, icecream`) and green barplots for fruits (`fruit`). Is this possible?

Comment: @G.Gip You can do `x2 <- x1[order(factor(names(x1), levels = c("jelly", "fruit", "icecream")))];
barplot(x2, col = c("yellow", "green", "yellow"))`